# Qt4 modular synth editing widget

Tags: c++, user-interface, open-source, qt4, synthesizer

I'm about to start writing a GUI for a modular synthesis app (like Alsa Modular Synth, Pure Data, Ingen) that will be used for patch (sound) editing.

What I need to do is something like this:

[image: Ingen]
<sub>(source: [drobilla.net](http://drobilla.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/ingen.png))</sub>

[image: Pure Data]

[image: hallseymrk1?]
<sub>(source: [mcgill.ca](https://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~clark/nordmodularbook/images/hallseymrk1.jpg))</sub>

So, basically, it's an area where I can draw some rectangles (boxes) that represent synth modules with input and output ports that I can connect with wires.

The problem is that I can't figure out how two create a widget for the editing area: Using a simple 2D drawing context where I draw the boxes manually seems to be the only logical way to do this, but doing this I loose all the great event management that qt gives me.

I'm wondering if there's the possibility of creating a custom layout that simply takes coordinates of created "boxes" and put them on the screen, so that I implement the boxes as subclasses of QWidget (and reusing qt's event handling system) and I add them to the window as I do usually.

Or maybe there's a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView.
This way you will be able to create a scene filled with items.
Each item can receive mouse events and you can manually paint it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom layout class that inherits from QLayout and overload the add(QWidget* w) function with the coordinates.

Personnally I'm using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. You can handle some events (as mouse event) and easily find your QGraphicsItem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Gephex sourcecode on http://www.gephex.org/download.php

they have already built such a widget for Qt, although might be a bit old code (QT3) and application specific.

ciao